# Angular2, pushing data into array and calling a method issue?

Tags: angular

Here, the scenario is, a `service.ts` method `getMetadata(data)` is taking data as input and storing in an array  `metaData = []`. 
The requirement is that when pushing of data into `metaData = []` is finished then call a method `getdata(metaData)`.

How to achieve that? Please help

### service.ts

```ts
public metaData = [];

getMetadata(data){
  console.log("data");
  this.metaData.push({data});
  /* when all pushing of data into metaData =[] is finished,
     then call a method getdata(metaData );*/

getdata(metaData );
}

getdata(metaData ){
  /*------------------------*/
}
```

### abc.component.ts

```ts
let Json1 = {
   "viewBys":["usstate"];
}
this.dataService.getMetadata(Json1 );  //here sending "Json1 " as a parameter
```

### bcd.component.ts

```ts
let Json2 = {
  "viewBys":["brand"];
}
this.dataService.getMetadata(Json2 );  //here sending "Json2 " as a parameter
```

### cde.component.ts

```ts
let Json3 = {
  "viewBys":["uscity"];
}
this.dataService.getMetadata(Json3 );  //here sending "Json3 " as a parameter
```

Comment: do you want to know when all components have finished adding the data? _all components are called once on a grid.component.ts dynamically._ - show the code

Comment: Yes, i want to know that whether all components have finished adding data or not. Please help.

Comment: show the code where you add them

Comment: I have added the code and these code are enough to solve the issue. Please help by looking above codes.

Comment: it's certainly not enough information

Comment: return metadata in the end of getMetadata function.

Comment: when all pushing of data into metaData =[] is finished,
     then call a method getdata(metaData ), please clarify by code.